# wordpress_redirect returns different headers for HEAD and GET requests

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

There's an odd behaviour I just noticed during some tests we're doing on one of our sites. We're verifying if the user isn't logged in and perform a `wp_redirect` in our theme's `header.php` like this:

```
if(is_page('gestionar-mentorias')){
  $post_id = get_the_ID();
  if(!members_can_current_user_view_post( $post_id ) && !is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect(
      get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'ingresa' ) ).'?redirect_to='.get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'gestionar-mentorias' ) ) 
    );
    exit;
  }
} ?>
```

This seems to be working perfectly both in our local and testing environments. However, the production site (which isn't under our control) doesn't do the redirect *some of the times*!

I was trying to debug this when I came across an odd behaviour. If I do a `curl -I http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/gestionar-mentorias/`, the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 23:47:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
X-Pingback: http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/?p=503>; rel=shortlink
Link: <http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/wp-json>; rel="https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

However, a `curl -v http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/gestionar-mentorias/` renders this result:

```
*   Trying 52.3.201.45...
* Connected to fedesoft.simianlab.com (52.3.201.45) port 80 (#0)
> GET /gestionar-mentorias/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: fedesoft.simianlab.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 23:47:09 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
< X-Pingback: http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/xmlrpc.php
< Link: <http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< Link: <http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/?p=503>; rel=shortlink
< Link: <http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/wp-json>; rel="https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API"
< Location: http://fedesoft.simianlab.com/ingresa/?redirect_to=http://fedesoft.simianlab.    com/gestionar-mentorias/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host fedesoft.simianlab.com left intact
```

Reading the man page for cURL, I saw that the difference between both commands is that `curl -I` performs a `HEAD` request, while `curl -v` is doing a normal `GET` request.

According to the spec, the HEAD method "[...] is identical to GET except that the server **MUST NOT** return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request **SHOULD** be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request."

My question is, then. why do I get two different responses?

Comment: Replace `wp_redirect()` with [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) and let me know if you're still having the issue. If you read the code it's recommended to use the `wp_safe_redirect` if you are redirecting to a page within your own site.